# Getting a 401 unauthorized error on One Login authentication grant type part 2 request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, onelogin

I am using MVC framework to make POST request to OneLogin API to get JWT. I am getting a 401 unauthorized message back at my PostAsync call in the code below.

Error look like following

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
  Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 04:21:23 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ol_oidc_canary_30=false; path=/; domain=.onelogin.com
  X-Powered-By: Express
  Content-Length: 77
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
```

Am i missing any parameters. I registered my localhost on One login dev account. Is there any setting there i need to update or change?

```
    public async Task<OidcTokenResponse> ProcessToken(string code, string clientSec)
    {

        string authorityToken = OneLoginAuthorityToken;
        var formData = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
       {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", OneLoginClientID),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSec),
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
      });

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
            const System.Net.SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;

            var res = await client.PostAsync(authorityToken, formData);
            var json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tokenReponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OidcTokenResponse>(json);
            return tokenReponse;
        }         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the redirect_uri again in this message - it is a security feature of the authorization code flow.

Also worth tracing the messages with a tool such as Fiddler to ensure that the messages sent over the wire are what you'd expect.

See steps 4 and 8 of my [messages write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) for something to compare against.

Comment: I added redirect URI and i am getting a 400 Bad request. I am sending scope and content-type in formData in above code. Still getting the same message back. Is there any issue with the way i'm making the Post request in this line ---- var res = await client.PostAsync(authorityToken, formData);?